# More efficient way of grouping rows by hour (using a timestamp)

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to show a log of daily transactions that take place. My current method is embarrassingly inefficient and I'm sure there is a much better solution. Here is my current query:

```
select ReaderMACAddress,
count(typeid) as 'Total Transactions',
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST("Timestamp" as TIME) between '05:00:00' and '11:59:59' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Morning(5am-12pm)',
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST("Timestamp" as TIME) between '12:00:00' and '17:59:59' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'AfternoonActivity(12pm-6pm)',
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST("Timestamp" as TIME) between '18:00:00' and '23:59:59' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'EveningActivity(6pm-12am)',
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST("Timestamp" as TIME) between '00:00:00' and '04:59:59' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'OtherActivity(12am-5am)'
from Transactions
where ReaderMACAddress = '0014f54033f5'
Group by ReaderMACAddress;
```

which returns the results:

```
ReaderMACAddress    Total Transactions  Morning(5am-12pm)   AfternoonActivity(12pm-6pm) EveningActivity(6pm-12am)   OtherActivity(12am-5am)
0014f54033f5               932                269                    431                          232                         0
```

(sorry for any alignment issues here)

At the moment I only want to look at a single Reader that I specify (through the where clause). Ideally, it would be easier to read if the time sections were in a single column and the results, i.e. a count function were in a second column yielding results such as:

```
Total Transactions          932
Morning(5am-12pm)           269
AfternoonActivity(12pm-6pm) 431
EveningActivity(6pm-12am)   232
OtherActivity(12am-5am)     0
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: [Please don't use `BETWEEN` for date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx). In this specific case, what happens to a row with a timestamp of 11:59:59.325 or 17:59:59.572? Probably a small number of rows would ever meet that criteria, but accuracy is accuracy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would first consider a computed column, but I believe from a previous post you don't have the ability to change the schema. So how about a view?

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.GroupedReaderView
AS
  SELECT ReaderMACAddress,
    Slot = CASE WHEN t >= '05:00' AND t < '12:00' THEN 1
                WHEN t >= '12:00' AND t < '18:00' THEN 2
                WHEN t >= '18:00' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT ReaderMACAddress, t = CONVERT(TIME, [Timestamp])
     FROM dbo.Transactions
  ) AS x;
```

Now your per-MAC address query is much, much simpler:

```
SELECT Slot, COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.GroupedReaderView
  WHERE ReaderMACAddress = '00...'
  GROUP BY Slot;
```

This will provide a result like:

```
1    269
2    431
3    232
4      0
```

You can also add `WITH ROLLUP` which will provide a grand total with the `Slot` column being `NULL`:

```
SELECT Slot, COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.GroupedReaderView
  WHERE ReaderMACAddress = '00...'
  GROUP BY Slot
  WITH ROLLUP;
```

Should yield:

```
1     269
2     431
3     232
4       0
NULL  932
```

And you can pivot that if you need to, add labels per slot, etc. in your presentation tier.

You could also do it this way, it just makes the view a lot more verbose and pulls a lot of extra data when you query it directly; it's also slightly less efficient to group by strings.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.GroupedReaderView
AS
  SELECT ReaderMACAddress,
    Slot = CASE WHEN t >= '05:00' AND t < '12:00' THEN 
                   'Morning(5am-12pm)'
                WHEN t >= '12:00' AND t < '18:00' THEN 
                   'Afternoon(12pm-6pm)'
                WHEN t >= '18:00' THEN 
                   'Evening(6pm-12am)'
                ELSE 
                   'Other(12am-5am)' 
                END
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT ReaderMACAddress, t = CONVERT(TIME, [Timestamp])
     FROM dbo.Transactions
  ) AS x;
```

These aren't necessarily more efficient than what you've got, but they're less repetitive and easier on the eyes. :-)

Also if you don't want to (or can't) create a view, you can just put that into a subquery, e.g.

```
SELECT Slot, COUNT(*)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT ReaderMACAddress,
      Slot = CASE WHEN t >= '05:00' AND t < '12:00' THEN 
                   'Morning(5am-12pm)'
                  WHEN t >= '12:00' AND t < '18:00' THEN 
                   'Afternoon(12pm-6pm)'
                  WHEN t >= '18:00' THEN 
                   'Evening(6pm-12am)'
                  ELSE 
                   'Other(12am-5am)' 
                  END
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT ReaderMACAddress, t = CONVERT(TIME, [Timestamp])
       FROM dbo.Transactions
    ) AS x
  ) AS y
  WHERE ReaderMACAddress = '00...'
  GROUP BY Slot
  WITH ROLLUP;
```

Just an alternative that still lets you use BETWEEN and may be even a little less verbose:

```
SELECT Slot, COUNT(*)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT ReaderMACAddress,
      Slot = CASE WHEN h BETWEEN 5  AND 11 THEN 'Morning(5am-12pm)'
                  WHEN h BETWEEN 12 AND 17 THEN 'Afternoon(12pm-6pm)'
                  WHEN h >= 18 THEN 'Evening(6pm-12am)'
                  ELSE 'Other(12am-5am)' 
                  END
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT ReaderMACAddress, h = DATEPART(HOUR, [Timestamp])
       FROM dbo.Transactions
    ) AS x
  ) AS y
  WHERE ReaderMACAddress = '00...'
  GROUP BY Slot
  WITH ROLLUP;
```

---

**UPDATE**

To always include each slot even if there are no results for that slot:

```
;WITH slots(s, label, h1, h2) AS
(
  SELECT           1, 'Morning(5am-12pm)'   , 5,  11
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Afternoon(12pm-6pm)' , 12, 17
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Evening(6pm-12am)'   , 18, 23
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Other(12am-5am)'     , 0,  4
)
SELECT s.label, c = COALESCE(COUNT(y.ReaderMACAddress), 0)
  FROM slots AS s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
     SELECT ReaderMACAddress, h = DATEPART(HOUR, [Timestamp])
       FROM dbo.Transactions
       WHERE ReaderMACAddress = '00...'
  ) AS y
 ON y.h BETWEEN s.h1 AND s.h2
 GROUP BY s.label
 WITH ROLLUP;
```

The key in all of these cases is to simplify and not repeat yourself. Even if SQL Server only performs it once, why convert to time 4+ times?

Comment: Many thanks again. I knew this was a bad way of dealing with the issue, and your queries and explanations go a long way to help better understand the error of my ways.

Comment: One question about your last option (with between): due to the nature of the Case function, when my queried ReaderMACAddress has no transactions within a Slot, the slot with no transactions is simply not displayed. Is there a way to show a 0 where nothing occured, similar to the results of method 1 (creating a view)?

Comment: That makes sense. Another issue I'm running in to is organizing the output in terms of time. Because I'm naming the rows morning, afternoon, etc (for reporting reasons) the Group By clause is ordering the rows alphabetically. Keep in mind I'm duplicating this query for 24 hours to get an hour by hour breakdown in addition to the slot method.

Comment: So see 1,2,3,4 inside the first subquery? You can renumber those to represent whatever order you want the slots to appear in, then add `s.s` to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` lines, and add an `ORDER BY`. If you're doing 24 hours then doesn't sound like you need the label at all - [just grab 24 rows from somewhere as I describe in this series](http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1). You're really changing the scope of this question over and over again - I think you should start a new question if my answer continues to not be enough.